# Where to view all access raw logs?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, log

Hi is there place where I can view all access to my magento server? I tried looking into `/var/log` but only see ssl.log which I thought that was it but when I visit my site I cannot see my activity being logged.  The reason why I'm asking is because recently I've been getting a lot of spam accounts despite my captcha and I speculate that its being created through programatically perhaps via POST but I cant track this down since I can't see the log.  Perhaps its in apache's log?  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To see all **Magento** logs:

```
cd var/www/yourproject/var/log
tail -f *
```

To see all **Instance** server logs:

```
cd var/log
tail -f *
```